# Including pybind and include Python.h

Tags: c++, reference, pybind11

I am trying to set up my environment with C++ and Python.
I need pybind11.
In some files of pybind11 there is the line `#include <Python.h>` included.
However it tells me

```
#include errors detected. Please update your includePath. Squiggles are disabled for this translation unit (C:\Users\d91675\Documents\GitHub\Test_PyBind\PyBind_Add.cpp). C/C++(1696)

cannot open source file "Python.h" C/C++(1696)
```

I would be happy if you could help me to understand the include functionality.

In places like `#include <iostream>` I guess this is directly included in the C++ installation.
I can also add modules myself with relative directory like `#include "subfolder/module.cpp"`.

Since I cannot find Python.h within the pybind11 library, I would guess, it is not available.
Do I need to create it with CMake?
e.g. as described here: https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/basics.html
Or what could be a reason this Python.h reference is missing?

I am really happy about an explanation for dummies.
Best regards,
Till

Comment: Python.h comes with your installation of Python. If you have installed Python, you have this file. You need to know where your Python installation is, find this file there, and add its folder to your include path. If you are using cmake, you probably need to tell it to find Python (I have no idea how this works on Windows).

Comment: I do not use CMake. By manually compiling, I needed to tell the tasks.json file, to include the subfolder where the Python.h file is located.
So thank you for your hint.